# Android: How to use map class for map functions?

Tags: android

I'm new in android. I can get map on emulator successfully and all code to do main functionality like setzoom, zoombuttons, annimateto etc. are written in main.java file.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);


            map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            control = map.getController();
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(33660175, 73055513);
        control.animateTo(point);
        control.setZoom(15);

    }
```

My question is that if I can write this in another class then how can I get all functionality by using class object in main.java class?

Comment: Could you explain this phrase in a better manner? "how can I get all functionality by using class object in main.java class" What is your main.java class? Is it another activity? Is it a MapActivity? What is "all functionality"? What is "class object", i.e what class is it referring to?

Comment: below i explain what i actually want.

Answer (score 0):

the code above given is my main.java class code. now i actually want to do that main.java class is used to show map activity but functions for map like

```
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    control = map.getController();
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(33660175, 73055513);
    control.animateTo(point);
    control.setZoom(15);
```

these functions are written in some other class and by using this class object in main.java file use these functionalities or also place or remove marker code written in another class and by using object of that class able to place or remove markers from map.

Comment: You are not speaking English. I tried reading what you said 3 times and I still can't understand anything. I doubt many other people will understand you. Please try to be clearer (I guess English isn't you first language).